# How to handle AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, com, process-state-exception

I am using a COM object (MODI) from within my .net application.  The method I am calling throws a `System.AccessViolationException`, which is intercepted by Visual Studio.  The odd thing is that I have wrapped my call in a try catch, which has handlers for `AccessViolationException`, `COMException` and everything else, but when Visual Studio (2010) intercepts the `AccessViolationException`, the debugger breaks on the method call (doc.OCR), and if I step through, it continues to the next line instead of entering the catch block. Additionally,  if I run this outside of the visual studio my application crashes. How can I handle this exception that is thrown within the COM object?

```
MODI.Document doc = new MODI.Document();
try
{
    doc.Create(sFileName);
    try
    {
        doc.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false);
        sText = doc.Images[0].Layout.Text;
    }
    catch (System.AccessViolationException ex)
    {
        //MODI seems to get access violations for some reason, but is still able to return the OCR text.
        sText = doc.Images[0].Layout.Text;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        //if no text exists, the engine throws an exception.
        sText = "";
    }
    catch
    {
        sText = "";
    }

    if (sText != null)
    {
        sText = sText.Trim();
    }
}
finally
{
    doc.Close(false);

    //Cleanup routine, this is how we are able to delete files used by MODI.
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
    doc = null;
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an `Exception` handler in (temporarily!) to trap all exceptions and see what the exception *actually* is?

Comment: @ChrisF - yes, see the last catch handler?  That should catch everything, including Exception and any subclass of Exception.  As well, Visual studio reports that the exception is System.AccessViolationException

Answer (score 327, accepted):

**EDIT** *(3/17/2021)*

Disclaimer: This answer was written in 2011 and references the original **.NET Framework 4.0** implementation, NOT the open-source implementation of .NET.

---

In .NET 4.0, the runtime handles certain exceptions raised as Windows Structured Error Handling (SEH) errors as indicators of Corrupted State.  These Corrupted State Exceptions (CSE) are not allowed to be caught by your standard managed code.  I won't get into the why's or how's here.  Read this article about CSE's in the .NET 4.0 Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035

But there is hope.  There are a few ways to get around this:

1. Recompile as a .NET 3.5 assembly and run it in .NET 4.0.
2. Add a line to your application's config file under the configuration/runtime element:
   `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true|false"/>`
3. Decorate the methods you want to catch these exceptions in with the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035 for details.

---

**EDIT**

Previously, I referenced a [forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104165841/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557105/unable-to-catch-accessviolationexception) for additional details.  But since Microsoft Connect has been retired, here are the additional details in case you're interested:

From Gaurav Khanna, a developer from the Microsoft CLR Team

> This behaviour is by design due to a feature of CLR 4.0 called Corrupted State Exceptions. Simply put, managed code shouldnt make an attempt to catch exceptions that indicate corrupted process state and AV is one of them.

He then goes on to reference the documentation on the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx) and the above article.  Suffice to say, it's definitely worth a read if you're considering catching these types of exceptions.

Comment: `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` works for me in .Net 4.5.

Comment: Thanks villecoder, you are a gem!  I've been dealing with this issue for weeks, trying to solve the root problem, and finally resigned myself to treating the symptom. Your solution is perfect.

Comment: ! To be aware: it is highly recommended to end the process after AccessViolationException that is a Corrupted State Exception (CSE). Otherwise it can lead to more critical errors.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful, although at first I got the impression that I need to do **all 3 steps** to be able to catch these exceptions, while it's actually a "logical `OR`" of the ways to do it. :)

Comment: @deerchao I hope you have read the 1st link provided in answer.  Handling CSE exceptions is a bad idea.

Comment: The last link is dead but it's accessible through here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120104165841/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557105/unable-to-catch-accessviolationexception

Comment: @CarlosTeixeira Thanks for the heads up. I've edited the answer to reflect the information from the wayback machine as opposed to just referencing the link.

Comment: @villecoder it seems `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` has been deprecated in .net 6

Comment: @Peter, I added a disclaimer that highlights that this answer references the .NET framework 4.0, not .NET.

Answer (score 22):

Add the following in the config file, and it will be caught in try catch block.
Word of caution... try to avoid this situation, as this means some kind of violation is happening.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For those who use c++/cli as a dll, the code should be added to the top .exe project.

Answer (score 11):

Compiled from above answers, worked for me, did following steps to catch it.

Step #1 - Add following snippet to config file

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Step #2

Add -

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]

[SecurityCritical]
```

on the top of function you are tying catch the exception

source: http://www.gisremotesensing.com/2017/03/catch-exception-attempted-to-read-or.html

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx, The SecurityCriticalAttribute is equivalent to a link demand for full trust.  I don't think the problem described necessitates demanding full trust.

Answer (score 3):

**Microsoft:** *"Corrupted process state exceptions are exceptions that indicate that the state of a process has been corrupted. **We do not recommend** executing your application in this state.....If you are **absolutely sure** that you want to maintain your handling of these exceptions, you must apply the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` attribute"*

**Microsoft:** *"Use application domains to isolate tasks that might bring down a process."*

The program below will protect your main application/thread from unrecoverable failures without risks associated with use of `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` and `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy>`

```cs
public class BoundaryLessExecHelper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void DoSomething(MethodParams parms, Action action)
    {
        if (action != null)
            action();
        parms.BeenThere = true; // example of return value
    }
}

public struct MethodParams
{
    public bool BeenThere { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void InvokeCse()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(123);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(123, ptr, true);
    }

    private static void ExecInThisDomain()
    {
        try
        {
            var o = new BoundaryLessExecHelper();
            var p = new MethodParams() { BeenThere = false };
            Console.WriteLine("Before call");

            o.DoSomething(p, CausesAccessViolation);
            Console.WriteLine("After call. param been there? : " + p.BeenThere.ToString()); //never stops here
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CSE: {exc.ToString()}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void ExecInAnotherDomain()
    {
        AppDomain dom = null;

        try
        {
            dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
            var p = new MethodParams() { BeenThere = false };
            var o = (BoundaryLessExecHelper)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(BoundaryLessExecHelper).Assembly.FullName, typeof(BoundaryLessExecHelper).FullName);         
            Console.WriteLine("Before call");

            o.DoSomething(p, CausesAccessViolation);
            Console.WriteLine("After call. param been there? : " + p.BeenThere.ToString()); // never gets to here
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CSE: {exc.ToString()}");
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(dom);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExecInAnotherDomain(); // this will not break app
        ExecInThisDomain();  // this will
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and see if that lets you catch it.

**EDIT*

Here is some [more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188710.aspx) that might be useful (it's a long read).

Comment: This answer is no longer complete accurate due to changes in the .NET framework.  Prior to 4.0 it is correct. Per section of AccessViolationException and try/catch blocks in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx