# Determine the root cause of a System.AccessViolationException

Tags: .net, powershell, reflection, kerberos, windows-10-desktop

I've reviewed other questions related to this one and specifically [Finding the cause of System.AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133971/finding-the-cause-of-system-accessviolationexception) but perhaps there is something else that could be looked at.

I have a powershell script, running under psversion v5.1 on windows 10 1909, that consistently crashes powershell with this exception when it attempts to retrieve the user's kerberos TGT using the following call:

`$SUCCESS = $Secur32::LsaCallAuthenticationPackage_KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE($LsaHandle, $AuthenticationPackage, [ref]$ProtocolSubmitBuffer, $KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST::GetSize(), [ref]$ProtocolReturnBuffer, [ref]$ReturnBufferLength, [ref]$ProtocolStatus)`

If I run the script interactively either in the powershell console or ISE it runs without issue and retrieves the user's TGT.  When the same script is invoked through a batch process running under the same user it gets the following .net exception in the event viewer.

> ```
> Application: powershell.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
> at Kerberos.secur32.LsaCallAuthenticationPackage_KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE(IntPtr, UInt64, KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST ByRef, UInt64, IntPtr ByRef, UInt64 ByRef, UInt32 ByRef)
> at DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Management.Automation.PSReference, System.Object, System.Management.Automation.PSReference, System.Management.Automation.PSReference, System.Management.Automation.PSReference)
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute8[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`9[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon)
> at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(System.Action`1<System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext>, System.Object, System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase)
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(System.Object, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.CommandParameterInternal[][], System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandBaseAst[], System.Management.Automation.CommandRedirection[][], System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon)
> at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(System.Action`1<System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext>, System.Object, System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase)
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(System.Object, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.CommandParameterInternal[][], System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandBaseAst[], System.Management.Automation.CommandRedirection[][], System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon)
> at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(System.Action`1<System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext>, System.Object, System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase)
> at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(System.Object)
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> ```

I've attempted to attach the PS debugger to the script process and all the variables are set correctly before the call and I've reviewed the function signature types, structs, enums, etc. but I'm stumped.  Is there anything in this stack trace that can shed some light on the underlying cause?

Comment: It's a lot like finding the root cause of a `NullReferenceException`: the code setting up things incorrectly so the whole thing ends in an access violation can be arbitrarily far removed from the call site. If you're lucky the code is very near to the call site and just fails to check for errors on allocating a buffer or somesuch. You need to look at the *whole* code, not this line. Start off by printing parameter values before the call. Managed stack traces for PowerShell code will be useless if you're not debugging the interpreter itself (which is probably not the problem here).

Comment: @JeroenMostert If any of the parameters to the call were null would you expect powershell to display them if printed in the debugger?  I have printed every input/output parameter to this call and all have the expected values and none are null, however, $ProtocolReturnBuffer is set to [IntPtr]::Zero as the function is intended to set this to a valid pointer on return.

Comment: `$null` values will by default not print as anything, no. If all parameters have values that's a start, but you can't tell from the values alone if (e.g.) pointers to buffers and sizes are valid, or if earlier heap corruption occurred due to incorrect calls. Debugging PS code that essentially does nothing more but call out to native functions is a pain; you may want to consider writing this bit in C#, because, if nothing else, the interop and debugging experience is much better (you can use Managed Debugging Assistants to catch some errors with interop, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this particular issue had nothing to do with the code.  The root cause happened to be that the powershell script was being invoked from a 32-bit cmd.exe.  Apparently this particular win32 api call is only accessible from a 64-bit process so I used the information provided at [How to launch 64-bit powershell from 32-bit cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055924/how-to-launch-64-bit-powershell-from-32-bit-cmd-exe) to resolve this issue.  I'm posting this response for the benefit of others who may run into the same issue.