# How to convert a date into DD/MM/YYYY/HH:MM:SS

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I wanted to convert date into `DD/MM/YYYY/HH:MM:SS` format. the date is given by the user.

I am  using the code below:

```
        string fromdate = context.Request.QueryString["fromdate"];
        string todate = context.Request.QueryString["todatedate"];

        DateTime fromDaten = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime toDaten = DateTime.MinValue;

        try
        {
            fromDaten = FormatDate(fromdate + " 00:00:00");
            toDaten = FormatDate(todate + " 00:00:00");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
```

I wanted to convert `fromdate` and `todate` into `DD/MM/YYYY/HH:MM:SS` format. When I try to do this I get `01/01/0001/00:00:00`.

in FormatDate i have the code below:

```
        try
        {

            string dateTimeString = todate;
            dateTimeString = Regex.Replace(dateTimeString, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);

            string inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            string outputFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string output = dateTime.ToString(outputFormat);
            return Convert.ToDateTime(output);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: what is the value in `context.Request.QueryString["todatedate"]`

Comment: What is `FormatDate`: it appears to convert a `string` to a `DateTime`, but you format dates when convert in the opposite direction.

Comment: var fromdate = $('#datepickerFrom').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();                                                                                                      var todatedate = $('#datepickerTo').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();

Comment: fromDaten=Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate).ToString(“dd/MM/YYYY/HH:mm:ss”)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Let me know if this works..

Answer (score 0):

That code is a bit of mess, try this:

```
    string fromdate = context.Request.QueryString["fromdate"];
    string todate = context.Request.QueryString["todatedate"];

    DateTime fromDaten = DateTime.Parse(String.Join("/", fromdate.Split("/".ToCharArray()).Reverse().ToArray()));
    DateTime toDaten = DateTime.Parse(String.Join("/", fromdate.Split("/".ToCharArray()).Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Comment: when i try to do this

Comment: my 'fromdate' is '10/09/2016' . in 'fromDaten' i got '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: i want '10/09/2016 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: @AnupaSankar 10/09/2016 is 10th Sept 2016 or 9th Oct 2016?

Comment: Updated to support reversed parameters

Comment: 10th sep 2016 @Anand

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
        string fromdate = context.Request.QueryString["fromdate"];
        string todate = context.Request.QueryString["todatedate"];

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromdate)||!string.IsNullOrEmpty(todate)) /* check  query string value */ 
        {             
         DateTime from=Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
         DateTime to=Convert.ToDateTime(todate);
         try
         {
          fromDate=from.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");/*Here you get date time in required format */
          toDate = to.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");  
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TryParse/TryParseExact` instead of try/catch which is more expensive and not a [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812726/is-it-ever-okay-to-catch-an-exception-and-do-nothing).

```
string fromDate = "2016/10/20/12:13:14";
DateTime fromDaten = DateTime.MinValue;
bool fromParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(fromDate, "yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm:ss", 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fromDaten);

// you may check fromParsed and handle invalid date/time
```

I have provided an example for `fromDate` only. You can create a parse function to deal with all your dates strings.