# Why try-catch block cannot handle the exception?

Tags: c#, exception, access-violation

*FSDKCam.GetVideoFormatList* is a method from external .NET dll. As you see the image, it throws an exception in try-catch block.

```
try
{
    FSDKCam.GetVideoFormatList(ref cameraList[0], out formatList, out count);
    if (count > 0) cmbCameraList.Items.Add(cam);
}
catch { }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it actually failing to catch the exception, or is your debugger set to stop when the exception is thrown?

Comment: You probably have set the debugger to break on all exceptions. Next!

Comment: it could also be visual studio Debugger issue, try to put some logging in the catch block (which you SHOULD do anyway, no reason to catch everything with empty catch block you are only hiding exceptions in this way); then try to run with no debugging and see if your logs are created...

Comment: Check villecoders' answer in [this question][1], it sounds like a similar issue


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception

Comment: An AccessViolationException occurs in unmanaged code, it's not actually in your program. Visual Studio is being helpful and telling you that it happened, but you can disable that option. You should find that this error does not stop your program from running right awa...

Comment: Run the EXE (without debugger): is the error shown to you? If not, you're catching the error because your debugger is set in this way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .NET 4, `AccessViolationException` is not catchable by default.

See the [legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517.aspx) configuration element. They did this because people have `try {} catch (Exception) {}` throughout their code and it is usually not a good idea to catch `AccessViolationException` (along with a few others) and continue.

Additionally, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Comment: I was just about to say this. The condescenders didn't notice it was an Access Violation exception.

Comment: So now the bad programmers are driving new CLR features/policies - it's Java all over again!