# List of exceptions that CAN'T be caught in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What is the list of exceptions that **CAN'T** be caught in .NET? Or where can I find such a list?

Comment: `NullReferenceException` can be caught. What made you think it can't be?

Comment: Why do you need such a list? Catch and handle exceptions you can deal with, catch and log exceptions that you can't, and let the OS nuke your process from orbit if something is so catastrophically wrong that the exception can't be caught.

Comment: or did you mean *shouldn't* instead of *can't*?

Comment: My bad, NullReferenceException was being thrown from an event and I wasn't catching it - didn't realize it was being thrown from an event and no my code - thought it was bypassing my catch statement

Comment: I come from Java where there are Runtime exceptions that can't be caught and others that can. Just was wondering if .NET was similar and if so, which exceptions behave like Java's Runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Denis: you can definitely catch RuntimeException in java, just like any other Throwable; the special thing about RuntimeException is just that they aren't checked, i.e. you can throw them without declaring them in the method declaration.

Comment: This question is in need of an updated answer. In .NET Core, the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute does nothing, meaning that it is no longer possible to catch any exceptions that indicate the program is in a corrupted state (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=net-8.0). This includes, for instance, AccessViolationException. I can't find a list anywhere, though - the Inside Out article that all the MSDN articles link to on this subject does not contain one.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The only exception that cannot be caught directly is (a framework thrown) [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx).  This makes sense, logically, as you don't have the space in the stack to handle the exception at that point.  From the docs:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default.

[ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) can be caught, but will always get re-raised, so has unique behavior.  From the docs:

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.

Also note that some `AccessViolationException` instances are corrupted state exceptions, and may not get handled *by default*.  These can be handled, but require extra handling via attributes.  For details, see [Handling Corrupted State Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035).

Comment: Note that you can suppress the `ThreadAbortException` rethrowing by calling `Thread.ResetAbort()`. (Note: don't do that.)

Comment: since this is the accepted answer can u add AccessViolationException (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception)

Comment: @Simon Thouhg you can often catch those with `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` - so they're not impossible to catch

Comment: so u dont think it is worth mentioning in this context?

Comment: also "You can catch NullReferenceException without issues." is no longer relevant to the edited question

Comment: @Simon - this is a good place to post your own answer about  AccessViolationException.

Comment: @Simon Put a mention of it in here -

Comment: @Reed :Entire Dotnet we have only exception ,we cannot handle it which is "StackOverflowException"?

Answer (score 7):

`NullReferenceException` can certainly be caught. Where did you get the idea from?

A `try {} catch {}` will catch non managed exceptions as well as managed ones (note that there is not exception clause on the `catch`).

The only one that cannot be caught is `StackOverflowException`, and `TreadAbortException` gets rethrown at the end of the catch.

Comment: That is not true.  Stack overflows will halt execution before you can catch the exception.  So there is at lease one.

Comment: @Oded, there are some edge cases in which that won't happen I believe I think with Enivornment.FailFast and with System.StackOverflow it doesn't

Comment: @Oded: It's just one of those interesting tidbits - I with StackOverflow could be caught somehow - it'd make life a lot easier in certain cases :(

Comment: @Reed sure you can... Keep a counter in your recursive function (increment every time you enter) if counter >= <some unreasonable number> then throw new LikelyStackOverflowException() - you'll get stacktrace.

Comment: @Denis: That's not the same as catching a "true" StackOverflowException.  Of course you can manage this yourself, but that wasn't what I was suggesting ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try this... (Tested on .NET Core 2.0)

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Type).GetType()).ToString()
```

A `System.ExecutionEngineException` that ignores all try/catch/finally blocks is thrown, even though it was deprecated saying the runtime NO LONGER THROWS this type of excpetion. Weird, eh?

The reason for this might be `typeof(Type).GetType()` returns `typeof(System.RuntimeType)` which is an internal type and a runtime intrinsic. There are validation of arguments by `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` regarding these types like `typeof(string)`, but the developers probably forgot to check this non-public type. As a result, an invalid `System.RuntimeType` is returned. When `ToString` is called, the invalid state causes the runtime to crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices` will be obsoleted in .NET 7 and throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` in .NET 8, so this won't stay long... https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md#entirety-of-binaryformatter-type-obsolete-as-warning

Comment: Curious. I wonder what will replace `GetUninitializedObject`, since many high performance serializers I've seen depend on it somewhere

Comment: Wow, it's so good, still working on .net core 6

Answer (score 4):

[ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)

Note:

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that **can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block**. When
>   this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread.

Comment: I wouldn't even count this as it **can** be caught, it's just that it has a side-effect of being re-thrown. Still, +1 for nice find.

Comment: This *can* be caught, and the re-throwing behaviour can be suppressed by calling `Thread.ResetAbort()`

Answer (score 4):

Well there are *some* exceptions that will always be re-thrown even if you catch them.
`StackOverflowException` is the only ones i can think of atm though. possibly `ThreadAbortedException`.

Answer (score 2):

Any exception that you can't reference by type because of accessibility can't be explicitly caught, but can be caught using the base `Exception` type.

For example, a `ContractException` in the code contracts framework is purposely made `internal` to its assembly so that you can't try to catch it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you mentioned `NullReferenceExceptions`.  `NullReferenceExceptions` are one of the main exceptions I catch.  The only one that I can think of off the top of my head is an Out of Memory exception or `StackOverflow`, because as soon as you are out of memory, execution is halted, and so there is a good chance that the exception can't be caught.

Answer (score 0):

SEHException can't be caught in some cases.  It can be thrown by unmanaged code.  A great SO thread on this topic appears here: [SEHException not caught by Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436597/sehexception-not-caught-by-try-catch)