# How to name a thread in a exportable way

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I am developping a multithreaded library in C++, which I compile then to a DLL.

For convenience, I use to name my worker threads with the following method provided by the msdn website : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx
Although I don't get exactly how it works, it does works like a charm as long as I load my DLL among a C++ project.

Now if I want to use it in a C# project, VisualC# breaks on the following line of the sample:

```
RaiseException( MS_VC_EXCEPTION, 0, sizeof(info)/sizeof(ULONG_PTR), (ULONG_PTR*)&info );
```

with this message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in myLibrary.dll
Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.
```

I unticked every kind of exception in `Debug`>`Exception`, but VC# still breaks on this line, then quit my app.

Is there a way of naming thread that is "inter-language-safe"?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEHException not caught by Try/Catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436597/sehexception-not-caught-by-try-catch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was the good answer to my question here, but it disappeared few days after.

Answer is: There is no way to name a thread. Raising this exception is a hack that allows Visual Studio to give it a name in its debugger. Since it is a Visual Studio trick, this method is not exportable.