# How to throw C++ error out side dll that am using in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I created a C++ dll and i want to use that dll in C#.
i created three functions in dll

`Initializ(),Start(),Release()`

in the initialize function i am opening a log file

```
static __declspec(dllexport) initialize()
{
    try
    {
       logfile lg("log.txt");
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
    throw e.what();
    }
}
```

after that i am calling this initialize function in C#

```
[DllImport("LgDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Initialize();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Initialize()
        catch (SEHException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my c# application where i am calling this function.
now i want that if log file is not opening in dll than it throw error outside the dll and the C# application has to decide weather to continue the application or abort the application or ignore the error.
please some body help me with sample C++ code.
so that the C++ dll send the exception outside the dll and wait for C# app response.

Answer (score 0):

`SEHException` is used for capturing Windows Structured Exceptions, and not C++ exceptions.  Structured exceptions (`__try`/`__except`) are implemented by the OS and are stable within a Windows process space.  C++ exceptions (`try`/`catch`)are implemented by the compiler and are only guaranteed to be stable within one compilation unit (usually a single DLL or exe).

The kinds of things that raise SEHExceptions are usually access violation, division by zero, out of memory, or other things that cause a process crash.  You probably shouldn't be generating these on your own, but if you really want then look into the [`RaiseException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552.aspx) function.

A better way of indicating a non-crash error state in the DLL would be to have your `Initialize`, `Start`, and `Release` functions return an error code.  The caller can then check this code and re-throw if needed.

See also:

[Difference between a C++ exception and Structured Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786647/difference-between-a-c-exception-and-structured-exception)

[SEHException not caught by Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436597/sehexception-not-caught-by-try-catch)