# How to handle System.AccessViolationException?

Tags: .net, exception, c++-cli

I'm using an external C library in my program coded in C++/CLI with the .NET framework 4. Sometimes the lib crashes and I get the message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

So I tried to handle it with a try/catch block:

```
try
{
  Init(); //< lib call which sometimes crashes
}
catch (Exception^ e)
{
  // handle the error
}
```

But the exception remains uncaught: my program crashes before entering the catch block.

How can I handle this exception to prevent my program from crashing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For clarity I copy/paste [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception) given in the comments by [Flot2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737655/flot2011) here:

> There are a few ways to get around this:
>
> - Recompile as a .NET 3.5 assembly and run it in .NET 4.0.
> - Add a line to your application's config file under the configuration/runtime element: `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true|false"/>`
> - Decorate the methods you want to catch these exceptions in with the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035) for details.