# Handling Error "WebDev.WebServer.Exe has stopped working"

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

Is there a way to handle the error "WebDev.WebServer.Exe has stopped working" in ASP.NET and keep the page running or even the just the WebServer running?  Or is this an impossible task and is essentially like asking how to save someone's life after they've died?

I have the error-causing code inside a try/catch block, but that doesn't make a difference.  I've also tried registering a new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler, but that didn't work either.  My code is below in case I'm doing something wrong.

Also to be clear, I'm not asking for help on how to prevent the error; I want to know if and when the error happens if there's anything I can do to handle it.

UPDATE 1: TestOcx is a VB6 OCX that passes a reference of a string to a DLL written in [Clarion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_(programming_language)).

UPDATE 2: As per @JDennis's answer, I should clarify that the `catch(Exception ex)` block is not being entered either.  If I removed the call to the OCX from the `try\catch` block it still won't reach the `UnhandledException` method.  There are essentially two areas that don't ever get executed.

UPDATE 3: From @AndrewLewis, I tried to also add a regular `catch` block to catch any non-CLS compliant exceptions, and this did not work either.  However, I later found that since .NET 2.0 on, all non-CLS exceptions are wrapped inside `RuntimeWrappedException` so a `catch (Exception)` will catch non-CLS compliant exceptions too.  Check out [this other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531077/will-clr-handle-both-cls-complaint-and-non-cls-complaint-exceptions) for more info.

```
public bool TestMethod()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    string input = "test";
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        TestOcx myCom = new TestOcx();
        result = myCom.PassString(ref input); // <== MAJOR ERROR!
        // do stuff with result...
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Add("Exception: " + ex.Message); // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
        return false;
    }
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    try
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
        log.Add("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        log.Add("Fatal Non-UI Error: " + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You pulled the plug from your TV, and try to watch a show. What is TestDll doing, where does it come from, what kind of object is it? Does it work fine by itself?

Comment: I just added an update to explain what the object does.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Wild guess, but can you add the attribute `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` to your `TestMethod` to see if you can catch the `Exception`? See also [How to handle AccessViolationException](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4759831/1822514)

Comment: Stupid question time: Have you tried running this in IIS instead of the built in webserver? You may find that the real exception is presented, or even no exception at all.

Comment: Are you sure // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED does never get called or if it just throws again? Try to just write a string without using the ex.

Comment: Awesome comments. I'll try all three and update soon.

Comment: In my test app, I was able to catch a [CSE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4759831/1822514) with only the attribute I mention above. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11056153/1822514) you may also need `[SecurityCritical]`.

Comment: @chuex - I added both `[System.Security.SecurityCritical]` and `[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]' and I still get the error.  @Pedro.The.Kid - that didn't work either.  @AaronH - trying now.

Comment: @AaronH - The error basically crashes the app pool (stops it in IIS) and the browser returns a 503 error. It doesn't hit the Global.asax so I don't even get a stack trace.  Interesting result, but doesn't get me closer to a solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You should try catching non-CLS compliant exceptions to make sure nothing is being thrown (keep in mind you don't want to do this in production, always be specific!):

```
try
{
    TestOcx myCom = new TestOcx();
    result = myCom.PassString(ref input); // <== MAJOR ERROR!
    // do stuff with result...
    return true;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Add("Exception: " + ex.Message); // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    return false;
}
catch
{
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: That's a great point Andrew.  I'll try that tomorrow and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  I still get the same error "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in WebDev.WebServer40.EXE".  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Doing some research, since .NET 2.0 all non-CLS compliant exceptions are wrapped inside `RuntimeWrappedException`, which derives from `Exception`. A `catch (Exception)` will catch both CLS compliant and non-CLS compliant exceptions.

Comment: Adding a link to @DanM comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404228.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Your code reads **//THIS NEVER GETS CALLED**.

If you catch the exception it is no longer un-handled. this is why it doesn't fire an unhandledexception event.

Comment: I see what you are saying @JDennis, so I will clarify in my question too: the catch block is never entered either.  It does not reach the call to the log message.

Comment: try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101097/unhandled-exception-not-caught-by-either-global-asax-error-handler-or-custom-iht