# How to catch OutOfMemoryException for an Azure FunctionApp

Tags: azure, azure-functions

An Azure FunctionApp has 1.5GB of RAM.
Sometimes my code goes above this value, and I would like to catch this exception.

Is it possible to do it? The simple try/catch doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a separate way to catch this particular type exception,  however as best practice you need to use exception handling in your code as given in the [**`docs`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages),

```
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: The catch block is not triggered. When I run locally I receive in the Console that there is an OutOfMemoryException, but it doesn't go to catch block. Maybe the function app stops immediately when there's no more memory left.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few exceptions you cannot (guaranteed to be able to) catch.

1. StackOverflowException - If you run out of the stack, then you cannot possibly execute code that very likely call another function.
2. OutOfMemoryException - Likely your handling code may need more memory to work.

[This answer gives a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13835973/975887)

Comment: Yes, this might be the cause. Thank you @Madushan

Comment: Please mark as answer if  this resolved the the original question 