# What Exceptions bypass catch blocks in .net

Tags: c#, .net, exception

So from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173161.aspx

> Once an exception is thrown, it propagates up the call stack until a catch statement for the exception is found.

So the implcation is that all exception typess can be either caught by a `catch(ExceptionType)` or a generic `catch`.

However this is plainly not true. For example `AccessViolationException` bypasses standard exception handling

[How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception)

So what other exceptions also bypass standard exception handling?

Comment: Do you mean, other than those in the accepted answer on that other question?

Comment: @RowlandShaw i threw out the one example to stop people answering "no exceptions bypass catch blocks". i am more curious if there is a definitive list somewhere or several answers to this can, cumulatively, become the definitive list

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a `StackOverflowException` is most likely unhandled, I'm not aware of others.

Comment: You should be while daring to answer such a question.

Comment: That is not handled for different reasons. The act of handling such an exception would require stack, which for obvious reasons is not available. Such an exception is handled by the operating system, which promptly terminates the application.

Comment: The question is what other exceptions bypass standard exception handling, and StackOverflowException bypasses such handling

Comment: Correct, you are not able to catch a StackOverflowException, though I wish you could catch it but not prevent it from bubbling. I wonder what the rationale there is.

Comment: @Brizio a good and obvious one which would have been a better example for me to use :) thanks