# Try/Catch doesn't catch exception

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

I have project with `FiddlerApplication` that saves some sessions for me. When I start the program  first launch after restart 100% fails and then 10% fails 90% works.

The biggest problem that when it fails it doesn't catch any exceptions in try/catch. Here is my code

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            browserToRun.GoTo("www.test.com"); 
            FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete +=  FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;

            //HERE it fails
            FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true, true);
            FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // it is not getting to here
            FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete -= FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
            FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!sess.fullUrl.Contains("test"))
            return;
            GlobalDownloadLink = sess.fullUrl;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            successful = false;

            throw new System.ArgumentException(ex.Message, "FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete");
        }
    }
}
```

My new Updated Apconfigwith new error Configuration System Failed to Initialize

```
<configuration>

  <runtime>
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
<configSections>

</configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="BrowserShow" value="Y"/>
    <add key="DebugCreate" value="true"/>
    <add key="FileName10" value="AccountActivity"/>
    <add key="FileName20" value="ForeignActivities"/>
    <add key="FileNameShar" value="MatbeotSchirim"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown? If you do not specify the exception (for example a `NullReferenceException e` catch), that will never be managed.

Comment: Additionally - I noticed you have a line `GlobalDownloadLink = sess.fullUrl;`. This is after your `return;` are you sure that's right?

Comment: By specifying Exception it doesn't catch every exception without distinction ?

Comment: "What exception is being thrown?" This is the problem i have brakePoints all over the functions and catch it is just fails with out catch exception

Comment: "GlobalDownloadLink " yes it is right if fullUrl.Contains("test") i dont need the url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some Exceptions are not getting caught by try..catch blocks unless you specify the attribute `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` on the function (`Main` function in your code). Of couse, the same could be accomplished by modifying the config file as Oxoron described.

Comment: one specifies this `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute to catch `Exception` that corrupt the applications memory state, like a 'AccessViolationException`.

Comment: Can you re-check if the exception is caugth or not, by adding a Console.Writeline? I also do not understand the purpose of re-throwing the exeption in the catch-block of FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete...

Comment: i think i found the problem i have watIn object and it is  thead and this FiddlerApplication is thear too,sow i need to seperate it to another class ,but thanx any way

Comment: @VovaPotapov , didn't understand what your real problem is, could you please describe your solution more? I guess you have separated FiddleApplicatio to an another class or something like that right? Having the same issue and Fiddler freezes my app so your answer will help me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Try to add 

`<runtime>
  <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>`

to the config file.
Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759831/3805175).

Comment: the old `CLR Exception Swallowing` policy.

Comment: after i add this i got another error- Configuration system failed to initialize

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code is that you're throwing `System.ArgumentException` from the *background* thread on which Sessions are processed; such exceptions aren't going to be caught by an exception handler on your main thread.

Beyond that, the way your code is written right now is just wrong; calling `Startup` and then immediately calling `Shutdown` will do nothing useful.