# How to catch any Exception which throwing Inisde the 3rd Party Dll From C# Applicaiton?

Tags: c#, exception

I am using one third party Dll. when i try to access some methods in that it throwing Accessviolation Exception and application got stopped 
working /crashing.

But i have put these code under the try {} catch {} statement but its application is not able to catch that exception.

e.g) code

```
//Object creation for 3rd party Dll classes.
Processor proc = new Processor();
Feedback feedback = new Feedback(this);

try
{
   Proc.Process(feedback); ====> Here i am getting Accessviolation exception
}
catch(Exception ex) ===> Here i changed to AccessviolationException but no use
{
MessageBox.Show("Exception occured "+ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle AccessViolationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception)