# System.AccessViolationException calling c++ function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

my c# application calls a c++ function of  an external DLL using dll import tag:

```
 [DllImport("UserAuthentication.dll")]
    private static extern int Validate(string pScrambeled, string szReadable, int flToUpper, string pstrErr);

int WINAPI ValidateAMOSBS(TCHAR *pScrambeled, TCHAR* szReadable, int flToUpper, TCHAR *pstrErr)
```

Only on one server, and when it is called by an ASP.NET application hosted on IIS, it thrown System.AccessViolationException. 
We try to change X86, X64 compilation and to reinstall VC++ redistributable without success. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Davide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how your function `ValidateAMOSBS` works in details. If, for example last argument `TCHAR` is an allocated buffer for error message then in import you should use `StringBuilder` type:

```
[DllImport("UserAuthentication.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Validate(string pScrambeled, string szReadable, int flToUpper, StringBuilder pstrErr);
```

and you should allocate buffer for error message before you call `Validate` function:

```
StringBuilder pstrErr= new StringBuilder(1000);
```

Same story is with other `TCHAR` parameters (if necessary).