# AccessViolationException on PropertyAccessor.GetProperty

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop

I have a problem with my VSTO add in. On some random machines I recieve an AccessViolationException trying to use PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

I couldn't find an explenation on the internet for why this exception accures.

Also it seems there is no way to catch this exception, i use a try catch block that catces (System.Exception), but it doesn't catch it and outlook crashes.

Any ideas on what can be the problem?

Comment: Please post the relevant snippets of your code. Does it only happen for a particular property?

Comment: What code do you have now? What parameters do you pass to the `GetProperty` method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your method with the attribute 
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]:

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    //Do something...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //This is catching ALL exception types 
    //even AccessViolationException
    //or OutOfMemoryException
  }
}
```