# Is there a way to predict that `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(code, pointers)` would throw an `AccessViolationException`

Tags: c#, exception, marshalling, access-violation

*I have a whole sequence of interlinked questions. I would like to know answers for all of them independantly, so *yes*, some of them appear to be X-Y questions; but I do want to know the solution to them anyway!. See end of question for list of other questions in this set.*

---

I have a situation in which calling `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(code, pointers)` throws an `AccessViolationException`.

Apparently this a VeryBadThing. So bad that `try...catch` just shrugs at me and wanders off for a fag ... which I didn't know was a thing :(

Suppose a premise of "calling `.GetExceptionForHR()` is what I want to do" (see other questions for a discussion of whether this is a good idea!).

Suppose further that whatever causes the `AccessViolation` is unavoidable in some scenarios.

Given those premises, is there any way to predict in advance that calling them method will blow up?
Some equivalent of `TryGetExceptionForHR()` that'll return `false` rather than blowing up my entire Program.

---

Other questions in this problem set.

- [C#: How do I prevent a pipe reading error, when closing the exe on one end of a DuplexChannel connected by Named Pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424672/c-how-do-i-prevent-a-pipe-reading-error-when-closing-the-exe-on-one-end-of-a)
- [Ascertain reason for Channel Fault in WCF+NamedPipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424741/ascertain-reason-for-channel-fault-in-wcfnamedpipes)
- [Is using the `Marshal` static class in otherwise normal C# code unwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424803/is-using-the-marshal-static-class-in-otherwise-normal-c-sharp-code-unwise)
- [Is there a way to predict that `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(code, pointers)` would throw an `AccessViolationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424851/is-there-a-way-to-predict-that-marshal-getexceptionforhrcode-pointers-would)
- [Is this a suitable use of `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431446/is-this-a-suitable-use-of-handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptions)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception

Comment: The *pointers* argument must be an IErrorInfo COM interface pointer.  The odds that you got a valid pointer are zero, this is not COM interop code.  Passing a bad pointer is indeed quite likely to trigger an AVE.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception. This question is asking "Can I predict in advance that if I call Marshal.GetExceptionForHR (under given circumstances). that it will throw an AccessViolationException, and if so, how can I predict this?" The question that it is marked as a duplicate of, on the other hand, is asking "how do I handle an AccessViolationException (that has already been thrown)?" These are clearly not duplicates of each other.

Comment: @SomeGuy I've had several comments agreeing with me (presumably kicked off by the discussion in meta.) I've therefore voted to reopen

Answer (score 0):

Just having a look at the Microsoft docs, `Marshall.GetExceptionForHR` doesn't throw an exception that can be caught.

Instead, they recommend using `Marshall.ThrowExceptionForHR` to get a thrown exception that you can then handle. This does not throw an exception when using a **success** HResult.

If you want to use `Marshall.GetExceptionForHR` then double-check that the correct pointer is being used. `IntPtr(0)` will use the current IErrorInfo interface while `IntPtr(-1)` will attempt to reconstruct the exception from just the code.

It's also possible that rather than throwing unexpected exceptions, `GetExceptionForHR` just returns the unexpected exception from a catch block e.g.:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   return ex;
};
```

Unfortunately, I can't be 100% certain at this point, I'm trying to track down the Marshall class on Microsoft's Github and I'll run some of my own attempts to see if I can get the same effect as yourself.

Related links:

- [ThrowExceptionForHR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.throwexceptionforhr?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_ThrowExceptionForHR_System_Int32_System_IntPtr_)
- [GetExceptionForHR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptionforhr?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_GetExceptionForHR_System_Int32_System_IntPtr_)