# SSH.NET uncatchable exception

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I'm trying to upload a file using SSH.NET using C# in a .NET Framework 4.5.2 project.

As soon as the `ConnectionInfo` constructor is invoked the application exits without any Exception not error message.
The event viewer is clean.

It seems I'm running into an `AccessViolationException`, that I know it's a serious problem and cannot be caught inside managed code but...
What am I doing wrong in using this library?
I just need to upload my file to a SFTP server.

Here is my code:

```
public override void Upload(FtpConfiguration conf, string file)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(file);

    try
    {
        // As soon as code reach this line the application crashes
        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(conf.Server,
                                                conf.Username,
                                                new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(conf.Username, conf.Password)
                                                );
        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
        {
            sftp.Connect();

            if (sftp.IsConnected)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conf.Subfolder))
                    sftp.ChangeDirectory(conf.Subfolder);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    sftp.UploadFile(fileStream, fi.Name, null);
                }
                sftp.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Just for debug purpose
        var error = ex.Message;

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried to decorate the method with `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` but still failed to catch the exception

Comment: Did you follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759831/1220550 (no experience with it, I just found it)

Comment: have you tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/legacycorruptedstateexceptionspolicy-element ?

Comment: Yes, already followed both links with no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose that all your `FtpConfiguration conf` properties used in both `ConnectionInfo` and `PasswordAuthenticationMethod` are all of type `string`, but I think you're missing the `port` which must be `int`. This should work.

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, port, user,
                                     new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user, pass));

using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{

      client.Connect();
      // Do some stuff.
      client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I just added the port (default 22) but the behaviour seems to be the same

Comment: Did you also check the values for `host`, `user` and `pass` when creating the `ConnectionInfo` object?

Comment: Yes, all the info are correct. FileZilla works fine with the same values

Comment: I tried both prepending "sftp://" and using the host by itself, but with the same result. But if it was a credential or host problem I would not expect such a serious issue... a normal exception would have been enough

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's the issue as your code seems right to me and mine was successfully tested. `host` must not contain the protocol, so some like "ftp.myhost.com" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.
My `Upload` method was inside a Task async chain.
Getting rid of the async solved the problem.