# C#: How to log stack trace of AccessViolationException before application crash?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, access-violation

I have some unsafe methods may throw AccessViolationException, it will stop at the line of code with debugger attached. but if run the application without debugger, the application just crashes, cannot log the stack trance to file.

Is there any way to find out which line causes the exception?

---

I'm using .NET 6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception)

Comment: @viveknuna not working for .NET 6