# Outlook Crashing on Spellcheck when COM Add-In tries reading message

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, comaddin, message-body

**OUTLOOK VERSION**:  2212  Build 15928.20282
32 Bit Outlook running on 64-Bit Win.

**PRE-CONDITION**:
Have a simple add-in which Overrides the **InspectorActivate** event handler.

**RECREATE**:
Open a new message Item 
type in a few words and make a spelling error 
Select the misspelled item, and **LEFT** click on one of the words suggested in the dropdown list.

When the event handler attempts to access the **Body** property of the Outlook MailItem a **System.AccessViolation** is thrown, and my exception handler is never reached.

```
mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook._MailItem;               

if (mailItem != null)
{
    try
    {
        if (mailItem.Body == null)  // System.AccessViolationException
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       log.Error(e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where did you get the `Inspector` instance in that case?

Comment: The object is coming from Outlook.   Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the following suggestion, and it's working

> This looks like an issue in the Outlook object model. I suggest that introduce a small delay before executing the logic which is now written in InspectorActivate. To achieve this, use the SendMessage/OnSendMessage machinery that we describe in section Wait a little; see the PDF file in the folder {Add-in Express}\Docs on your development PC. When the OnSendMessage event occurs and you filter out your message, get ActiveInspector and execute your logic for that Inspector object.

For the code, look towards the bottom of the page
[Solution at Bottom of page](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=16515#postform)

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the message body using the Word editor - worst case, you get an exception that you can handle:

```
var body = Inspector.WordEditor.Content.Text;
```

Comment: Always useful.  Thanks.   I believe, I've found the issue.  Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception) page explains how to handle such exceptions in the managed code starting from the .net framework 4.0.

You may also try using the `HTMLBody` property instead. If it gives the same results I'd suggest retrieving the `WordEditor` instance in that case. You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The `Body` property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. To preserve any formatting you need to use the `HTMLBody` or the Word editor instance.

Comment: Good stuff!  Thanks.   Especially about the access violation.  I really haven't dealt with SEH outside of C++.